# Represent object present at a position inside an array in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In aggregation i am trying to project an `object(which is an array)` which is present at `position 7 inside an array`. For example i have fields as below

```
{
        "$project": {
            "result": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": ["$coupon_type", 1]
                    },
                    "then": ["$_id", "$coupon_type", "$nonce", "$total_coupons", "$amount", "$curr_ctr"],
                    "else": ["$_id", "$coupon_type", "$nonce", "$total_coupons", "$amount", "$curr_ctr", "$coupon_codes", {
                        indexes: conditions
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            obj: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$result", 7 ] } // here how to project indexes.

    }
```

So now for `coupon_type: 0` i will project my result as `["$_id", "$coupon_type", "$nonce", "$total_coupons", "$amount", "$curr_ctr", "$coupon_codes", { indexes: conditions}]`.

Now the field i want to project in my next pipeline is 'indexes' so i tried to write `$arrayElemAt: [ "$result", 7 ]` which is giving me 7th index element which is right but how should i represent object 'indexes' present at this 7th position.

In short i want to write something like this `$arrayElemAt: [ "$result", 7 ].indexes` which is not the right way to point to an abject.

Can anyone please tell me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the project stages and use  `$let` to project the index.

```
$project: {
    indexes: {
        $let: {
            vars: {
                obj: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [{
                        "$cond": {
                            "if": {
                                "$eq": ["$coupon_type", 1]
                            },
                            "then": ["$_id", "$coupon_type", "$nonce", "$total_coupons", "$amount", "$curr_ctr"],
                            "else": ["$_id", "$coupon_type", "$nonce", "$total_coupons", "$amount", "$curr_ctr", "$coupon_codes", {
                                indexes: conditions
                            }]
                        }
                    }, 7]
                }
            },
            in: "$$obj.indexes"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually sorry i didn't uploaded my whole code, i only want to project obj only if coupon_type equals to 0 because as for coupon_type 1 7th index of result does not exist. but according to your code even for coupon_type 1 you will try to project obj.indexes so can you please change that in your code ??

Comment: I didn't change anything. Even your code in the second project is doing the same thing. You can move the code to your second project and use $let to extract the index. is that what you want ?

Comment: can you just tell me one thing suppose i want to perform three operation in single projection now how can i use $let to perform that, then my problem will be perfectly solved. I thought about using three times $in but i don't think that will work. Also thanks a lot for helping me out of here man :)

Comment: $let is used to store intermediate result so you can apply to each document. See if it makes sense to you. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/

Comment: yes i have already seen this after i have seen this in your answer, i really liked this idea of using this, i just want to ask suppose consider this use case where i have `var a` and then i want to `add 2 in a` and after that i want to `add 3 in a` now can i do these two value change operations on `a` using `$let` because i will have to use two times `$in`, first time to change value of `a to 2` and second time to change its value `to three` ?? i am one last step away from solution please help i know it is bothering you.

Comment: Its okay man. You can think $let as a var which only has scope for each document and it will allow to perform calculations in single document. You can create as many variables as you want and use them together. I don't understand when you say `then`. Are you trying to do some operation on a embedded array ? See if you can formulate this into a question with some examples if its not a big deal.

Comment: Hey i found my solution thanks for telling me about `$let`, i have used `$let` two times, first i perform operation in `$in` and second time i took that value which was given by `$in` as another `$let var` and then again tried to do my operaton using `$in` and it is workin perfectly fine thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by adding a second $project stage:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([{
            "$project": {
                "result": {
                    "$cond": {
                        "if": {
                            "$eq": ["$coupon_type", 1]
                        },
                        "then": ["$_id", "$coupon_type", "$nonce", "$total_coupons", "$amount", "$curr_ctr"],
                        "else": ["$_id", "$coupon_type", "$nonce", "$total_coupons", "$amount", "$curr_ctr", "$coupon_codes", {
                            indexes: conditions
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                obj: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$result", 7 ] } 

        }, 
        {"$project": {
                obj: "$obj.indexes" }
        } 
])
```